# jQuery and ASP.NET drop down problem

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, ajax, event-handling

I have a drop down in an ASP.NET page. Whenever the value of the drop down changes an ASP.NET AJAX request is made to the server. I also attached a jQuery "change" event handler to that list to execute some code when the value is changed. So, probably two different event handlers are being attached to the same drop down, and it's causing some problems, i.e., sometimes wrong drop down values are sent to the server. I don't know why is this happening but I think attaching two different event handlers to a same drop down may be the reason.

Can anyone tell me what is the problem here? If what I guessed is true, then is there any other way to execute some custom javascript code before asp.net AJAX request is sent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the JQuery change() binder respects all previous binds (won't break them). If you want to be sure the methods are called in the correct order, bind ONE master method to the change event, and have that one method call both methods (the qsp and the jquery) **in the right order** :)

Comment: how can I call the ajax function which does the ajax request to the server ? I am using "postback" property to send ajax request.....